# AnimatedContainer in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I developed the below animatedcontainer

[Animated container](https://streamable.com/vlyi0v)

I would like to make the textfield and button that appears after pressing on the container to appear in a fading way or smoother, currently they appear from the bottom.

Any suggestions on how to make that?

```
       duration: Duration(milliseconds: 850),
       width: pressed ? 570 : 250,
       height: pressed ? 280 : 50,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AnimatedOpacity instead of AnimatedContainer

Comment: But I want the container to increase in size whenever I press on it then switch the inside widgets to something else and let them appear in a fading way

Comment: you can wrap an Animated container with animated opacity... Opacity handles the fade while container handles the rest